# Where does @uml.property tag in javadoc come from?

Tags: java, uml, code-generation, javadoc

I've stumbled across a piece of code written by someone before me who has left the company; I am the heir to his code.

What are these tags? I found them only in one specific Class file and they seem to be holding either little or lots of value. I just don't know whether or not they're junk.

The Class is not referencing any external "uml" libraries.

*Here is a full example...*

```
/**
 * @uml.property  name="devs"
 */
public ArrayList<String> getDevs() {
    return devs;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These tags come from [Soyatec UML plugin](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/documentation/com.soyatec.euml2.doc/annotations/xdoclet/property.html). Here is also detailed explanation of the tag. The code was apparently generated from the UML diagram. The generator added that tag to the generated fields.

If you do not use the UML plugin any more, you may delete them. It will not influence your code. However the parameters (`name`, `readOnly`, `multiplicity`, `dimension`, `ordering`, `container`, `default`) can tell you something about the field, what the intention of the designer was - see the link above.

If you want to keep the tags in the code but want to get rid of the warnings, see this question: [Killing Javadoc warnings for specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12591175/2886891)